# In a *for* function, can I keep stacking values?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, mean

I currently have lots of excel files with the same fields but for different sectors. I'm trying to create a function that allows me to get the total mean from the "sulfate" field in all my excel sheets.

This is the code I currently have:

```
Mean_Pollution<-function(directory,pollutant,id = 1:332){
  directory <- c("001","002","003","004")
  for (x in directory){
    print(paste("Reading",x,"file"))
    temp = read.csv(paste(directory.path,x,".csv",sep = ""))
    print(paste("Finished reading",x,"file"))
    i = print(mean(temp$sulfate,na.rm = TRUE))
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what "stacking" means. Appears that you think `directory.path` will be operating on  the vector `directory` to give you a set of paths. Not the way R works. Learn to use `list.files`. I also think the Johns Hopkins Coursera course suggests that you use their website for homework questions. Nonetheless, you will be able to find lots of worked Coursera homework questions with a search on "[r] pollutant". (I just found 290 of them.)

Comment: Yes , indeed, but I wanted to fully understand the code. It would be an useful tool if I could apply it to other examples. That's why I brought it here, to see if there was a way for every time an X mean value was given I could catch that value and use it later on.

Comment: You have posted code with no dataset and no description of how that function was being called or what results or errors you might be seeing.  So it doesn't make much sense for use to try to offer you advice in he absence of a specific constext.

Comment: How are your Excel sheets organized? what is the name of your directory? And what is the `id` argument for? Why do you use `directory.path` at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a coursera homework question and there are lots of answers on SO. Searching for pollutant on SO will turn up several.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have everything you need and there are plenty of questions like this, but I'll provide an example. The assumption here is that everything is in 1 folder. I'll use my own folder:

```
setwd(dir = "C:/Users/Evan Friedland/Documents")
# Put some fake data in a fake folder
dir.create("Test_Folder")
setwd(dir = "C:/Users/Evan Friedland/Documents/Test_Folder")
n <- 5 # let's write 5 csv files
for(i in 1:n){
  write.csv(data.frame(madeupX = LETTERS[sample(1:24, 100, T)], sulfate = rnorm(100)), # fake data
            paste0(sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv")) # fake names
}
csvnames <- paste0(sprintf("%03d", 1:n), ".csv")
```

Now all you need to do to "stack" the mean of each file is initialize an empty vector, loop through them and save each result to an element of the vector.

```
means <- numeric(n) # intialize numeric type vector, n long
names(means) <- csvnames # name each element for fun
means <- sapply(1:n, function(x){ # used sapply instead of a for loop but either is fine
  cat("+ ",csvnames[x],"\n") # print which csv is running
  mean(read.csv(paste0(csvnames[x]))$sulfate) # return the mean of the sulfate col
  })
#+  001.csv 
#+  002.csv 
#+  003.csv 
#+  004.csv 
#+  005.csv 
means # print results
#[1]  0.007859499  0.077447995  0.048796633 -0.101449790 0.224429258
```